# Webscraping the contents of a tables

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, html-table

Hi I am trying to use Python and Beautiful Soup to scrape a webpage. There are various tables in the webpage with results that I want out of them, but I am struggling to:
1) find the right table
2) find the right two cells
3) write the cells 1 and 2 into a dictionary key and value, respectively.

So far, after making a request, and parsing the HTML, I use:

```
URL='someurl.com'

def datascrape(url):
    page=requests.get(url)
    print ("requesting page")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    return(soup)

soup=datascrape(URL)

results = {}
for row in soup.findAll('tr'):
    aux = row.findAll('td')
    try:
        if "Status" in (aux.stripped_strings):
            key=(aux[0].strings)
            value=(aux[1].string)
            results[key] = value
    except:
        pass
print (results)
```

Unfortunately "results" is always empty. I am really not sure where I am going wrong. Could anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: There could be multiple reasons including ( but not limited ) to dynamically generated tables. Someone could answer if you can provide the url and the expected results.

Comment: Have you looked at the requests? Did you actually look at the real HTML that is being requested (not though your browser)? I am going to guess what your trying to scrape is not actually in the page your requesting. Please do some investigating of all the requests that are being made when you load that website.

Comment: It is impossible to help as we cannot replicate your issue without targeted site

Comment: This is an example of a URL I am trying to scrape: https://sitem.herts.ac.uk/aeru/bpdb/Reports/2070.htm
Yes I have looked at the HTML returned, it seems to be fairly straight forward, though I don't know a lot about HTML really.

Comment: It would help if you indicated exactly the values you expect to see returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using findAll() instead of find_all() as I'm fairly new to web-scraping, but nevertheless I think this gives you the output you're looking for.

```
URL='http://sitem.herts.ac.uk/aeru/bpdb/Reports/2070.html'
def datascrape(url):
    page=requests.get(url)
    print ("requesting page")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,     
"html.parser")
    return(soup)

soup=datascrape(URL)

results = {}
table_rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    try:
        for i in row:
            if "Status" in i:
                key=(row[0].strip())
                value=(row[1].strip())
                results[key] = value
    else:
        pass
print(results)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If just after the Status and Not Applicable you can use positional nth-of-type css selectors. This does depend on position being the same across pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://sitem.herts.ac.uk/aeru/bpdb/Reports/2070.htm'
page=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
tdCells = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('table:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-of-type(1) td')]
results = {tdCells[0] : tdCells[1]}
print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks I had not come across this before. I think it will be helpful.